# How to find out all the endpoints being checked by wcf while debugging

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a simple web endpoint built using wcf, that is being hosted within a service. While I am trying to debug I am not hitting the method that I intend to. Getting an "Endpoint not found" exception.
The constructor of the class that has the implementation is however being called.

How can I find out all the endpoints that are being checked against so that I can change my url accordingly when I call from a browser?

Comment: You can check by following the steps:
1. Are there any parameters missing in your configuration file, such as address Binding Contract?
2. Check whether the port of the address in the configuration file is the same as the port of the address you access.

Comment: there are some parts of the URI that are generated dynamically based on the machine name, code for which comes from a third party dll. 
So once the service starts running, I want to find out all the available endpoints